# Button margin bottom doesn't work when i set Visibility of progress to GONE

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a button in RecyclerView and one progress below this button, for downloading work when button pressed progress will be show and when download complete progress hide.

In android 5 margin looks good, but in android 4 it have little problem.

See this picture, it's a very clear explanation for my problem.

[image: RecylerView and Button]

And this is my xml codes :

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn_down_question"
  android:layout_width="64dp"
  android:layout_height="34dp"
  android:layout_below="@id/txt_desc_question"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
  android:background="@drawable/blue_button_style"
  android:text="دریافت"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="12sp"/>

<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/prgDownload"
  android:layout_width="72dp"
  android:layout_height="4dp"
  style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
  android:layout_below="@id/btn_down_question"
  android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INVISIBLE instead of GONE.

Because

INVISIBLE:

This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

GONE:

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding bottom to parent layout and don't give margin bottom to progressBar.